# Why IPerspectiveListener.perspectiveChanged() isn't called when an editor is closed?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, perspective

If I open an editor the `IPerspectiveListener.perspectiveChanged()` will be called but if I close an editor it won't. Why?

I thought it must be called with `IWorkbenchPage.CHANGE_EDITOR_CLOSE` as the value of `changeId` argument.

Comment: The code in WorkbenchPage does make this call when editors are closed. How are you closing the editor?

Comment: I've opened and closed editors manually. In the first case the debugger stopped in the method, in the second - not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse bug [392963](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392963) which has been open for some time and doesn't look like it is being worked on.

An alternative is to use `IPartListener` (or `IPartListener2`) which will also tell you about parts being opened and closed.